# How can I change a slice in the function without return?

Tags: go, slice

my code like this

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

func Pingpong(s []int){
    fmt.Printf("len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",len(s),cap(s),s)
    s=append(s,3)
    fmt.Printf("len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",len(s),cap(s),s)
}
func main(){
    s:=make([]int,1,2)
    fmt.Printf("value:%v,len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",s[0],len(s),cap(s),s)
    Pingpong(s)
    fmt.Printf("value:%v,len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",s[0],len(s),cap(s),s)
}
```

the answer like this

```
value:0,len:1,cap:2,address:0x1040a128
len:1,cap:2,address:0x1040a128
len:2,cap:2,address:0x1040a128
value:0,len:1,cap:2,address:0x1040a128
```

Why? Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: Read https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals and https://blog.golang.org/slices and take the Tour of Go from https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Answer (score 0):

Notice how whenever you append to a slice in go, `append` returns a new slice. This is because slices are backed by a fixed-size array, and multiple slices can be backed by the same array. In this case, append needs to return a new slice because the backing array may have changed. (For example creating a larger backing array to fit new items)

Your method is very similar to `append`, and it has the same limitations. You'll need to return the new slice descriptor any time you modify the bounds. Basically any time you set your slice equal to something else, either by using append or taking a subslice, you have to return the new descriptor you made.

Comment: thank you for answer me this question,but I have found the reason about it.

Comment: func Pingpong(s *[]int){
 fmt.Printf("len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",len(*s),cap(*s),s)
 s=append(s,3)
 fmt.Printf("len:%v,cap:%v,address:%p\n",len(*s),cap(*s),s)
}